# What's #define LINUX for?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a char device driver for Linux, and I saw in some example the following lines

```
    #define __KERNEL__             
    #define MODULE                             
    #define LINUX
```

I found in the internet that `#define __KERNEL__` means that the code is part of the kernel, and that `#define MODULE` means that it's not a permanent part, but for some reason I can't find what `#define LINUX` is for?
In some examples I saw only the first two defines, and in other all the three defines.

So my question is: what is  `#define LINUX` for?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be used from  3.17 (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.16;i=LINUX) onward. I wouldn't worry about it. Just a macro whose existence you can test for (as with any macro) and use to direct the preprocessor.

Comment: `In some examples I saw only the first two defines, and in other all the three defines.` - Those examples are wrong: `__KERNEL__` and `MODULE` macros are defined by the KBuild system when it is needed. Driver's code may only **check** them for differentiate kernel/user and builtin/module modes it is compiled.